# I am needing to extract the variables from the end of a large string/dict/something

Tags: python, string, discord, discord.py

I am looking for a simple solution that can be used here: This is my code.

```
import discord
import json
from discord.ext import commands
print("Starting bot...")

TOKEN = ''
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    embeds = message.embeds
    for embed in embeds:
        emb = str(embed.to_dict())
        if 'owned' in emb:
            owned = object('title')
            print(owned)
print("Bot is ready!")
client.run(TOKEN)
```

(I do have a discord bot token in place I removed it to show y'all) Anyways my goal is to be able to take emb, which comes out of the script looking like this:

```
{'footer': {'text': 'Item Type: Sellable'}, 'thumbnail': {'width': 75, 'url': 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/714980893999104051.png', 'proxy_url': 'https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/c4teYBjoGAhxnygEZ5F2GlHWzReCIg_xEOX1PPtZdIQ/https/cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/714980893999104051.png', 'height': 75}, 'color': 15684432, 'type': 'rich', 'description': "This item's purpose is to be collected or sold. Nothing more, nothing less.\n\n**BUY** - Not able to be purchased\n**SELL** - ⏣ 1,680 (multiplier included)\n**TRADE** - 2k - 7k", 'title': '**Common Fish** (697 owned)'}
```

and to be able to take only the last part, the 697. My major problem here is that this will sometimes be 500, sometimes only be 2 but I would like to be able to extract that and use it as a variable. Keep in mind that the length of the lines will vary. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I have to write this in answer. This is very easy actually you just need basic python string manipulation skills for this

let's assume, your dictionary/json is assigned to a variable `x`

```
x = {'footer': {'text': 'Item Type: Sellable'}, 'thumbnail': {'width': 75, 'url': 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/714980893999104051.png', 'proxy_url': 'https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/c4teYBjoGAhxnygEZ5F2GlHWzReCIg_xEOX1PPtZdIQ/https/cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/714980893999104051.png', 'height': 75}, 'color': 15684432, 'type': 'rich', 'description': "This item's purpose is to be collected or sold. Nothing more, nothing less.\n\n**BUY** - Not able to be purchased\n**SELL** - ⏣ 1,680 (multiplier included)\n**TRADE** - 2k - 7k", 'title': '**Common Fish** (697 owned)'}
```

We can get the title by `x['title']`

First step is splitting at first opening bracket `(`

which would make it `x['title'].split('(')`

which will give us an output as list `['**Common Fish**', '697 owned)']`

then we will index 1, because we need the second item in this list (because the number you need is in there)

which would make it `x['title'].split('(')[1]`

now we further split it, but this time we provide no arguments to `.split()` which will just split on spaced characters.

which would make it `x['title'].split('(')[0].split()`

with that, you will again get a list like this:
`['your desired number', 'owned)']`

Then all there is left is to index this list to 0!

which would make it `x['title'].split('(')[1].split()[0]`

which will give us `your number (697 in this case)`

Works with any `x` number

```
x = {'footer': {'text': 'Item Type: Sellable'}, 'thumbnail': {'width': 75, 'url': 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/714980893999104051.png', 'proxy_url': 'https://images-ext-1.discordapp.net/external/c4teYBjoGAhxnygEZ5F2GlHWzReCIg_xEOX1PPtZdIQ/https/cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/714980893999104051.png', 'height': 75}, 'color': 15684432, 'type': 'rich', 'description': "This item's purpose is to be collected or sold. Nothing more, nothing less.\n\n**BUY** - Not able to be purchased\n**SELL** - ⏣ 1,680 (multiplier included)\n**TRADE** - 2k - 7k", 'title': '**Common Fish** (697 owned)'}

my_num = x['title'].split('(')[1].split()[0]
```

Comment: Hey- Now I am getting an error that I am getting this error message: "TypeError: string indices must be integers", when I looked into this it said that it was likely due to having something that was not an integer within the brackets, when I changed them to parenthesis, I get this error "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable", any advice?

Comment: contact me on discord `Pizerite#5648`